# Jimp returning wrong mime type

Tags: javascript, image, bitmap, buffer, jimp

I wrote a bitmap parser that should return jimp object (image)
and im getting error "Unsupported MIME type: `audio/mpeg`"

Here's the code:

```
var mid = Buffer.from(mapbitmap, 'base64');
var image2 = await Jimp.read(mid);
```

the mapbitmap is the bitmap that im trying to parse,
it's not empty or something.

Detailed error:

```
Error: Unsupported MIME type: audio/mpeg
    at Jimp.throwError (D:\FrostX\Develop\javascript\sandbox\node_modules\@jimp\utils\dist\index.js:21:13)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (D:\FrostX\Develop\javascript\sandbox\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\utils\image-bitmap.js:159:32) {
  methodName: 'constructor'
}
```

I don't know what to do about this,
I just started learning javascript yesterday
and basically don't know how to fix this,

It should be returning image instead of audio.

Answer (score 1):

from the error it looks like Jimp is reading your bitmap as an audio file, to fix it you need to parse your data as an image:

```
  const Jimp = require('jimp');

  var mid = Buffer.from(mapbitmap, 'base64');
  var image = await Jimp.read(mid, { mime: Jimp.MIME_BMP });
```

this snippet should work

Comment: it works, but my other part of the code is still not working for some reason, but its a different problem now. (update: found it its still error with mime, but not really, `TypeError: cb.call is not a function`